# is it possible to have self defined source data to create pivot table?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. I have to create a pivot table from a worksheet named as "raw". Unfortunately, sometimes the name of the worksheet can be some other names such as test or even experiment.

My code is as follow to use a macro to create a pivot table.

```
Range("A1:Z1048576").Select

Sheets.Add

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"raw!R1C1:R1048576C12", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12 _
).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:= _
"PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

As you can see, my 'SourceData:= raw' which is the name of the worksheet. As I have explained earlier that this raw can be any name by the user it self, so i was wondering if it is possible to create a pivot table from a worksheet that has names that user that uses the macro, self defined its name.

I have also tried using rename coding, but i have to know the worksheet name before i can do anything else..

Follow up:

My GUI has an open and start button to start the whole thing.

```
Private Sub testFinder_Click()
    'Open button
    Dim fileToOpen

    fileToOpen = Application _
    .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub

    TextBox1.Value = fileToOpen
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    'start button

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TextBox1.Value, Origin:=437, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Then after that, will be the code for the pivot table.

Comment: Would it be okay if the pivottable code runs in the start button?

Comment: should be ok.. but will it be quite different if i dont want to use it at the start button?

Comment: Yes slightly as I need to set my variables accordingly. Would you be running it from a 3rd button?

Comment: at the moment yes.. i have another button specially for macro.. but will have to change it soon...

Comment: Ok, I am giving you an example shortly in a 3rd button. Also amending then 2nd button code slightly. I am assuming that the pivot has to be generated in a new sheet in the workbook from which the macro is being called?

Comment: yup.. it has to be generated in a new sheet say sheet1

Comment: hi sid, i will have a look at your code later when u have get it posted.. thank you again... if there is any problem will need your help again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ActiveSheet from the macro but that might give you undesired results if the active sheet is not the actual sheet which has the data. Here is an alternative. Why not let the user select the Pivot range? You can then use that range in your code?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select the range for the pivot", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox "The Pivot Range is " & Rng.Parent.Name & "!" & Rng.Address
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

**DISCLAIMER**: *I always test my code before posting but in the absence of the Text File in the current scenario, I cannot test the below code. Also I have not done any error handling so do let me know if you get any errors and we will take it from there.*

Button1 Code remains unchanged. I have changed the 2nd Button code slightly and added the 3rd button. Also note that I am not using hard coded numbers like 1048576. No point taking all rows into consideration if your data is say only till 2000 :)

**TIP**: When distributing the application to your user, remember to include error handling. Users often don't behave like the way you expect them to behave. For example what if the user clicks on the 2nd button before clicking on the 1st button OR what if the user clicks on the 3rd button before clicking on the 1st or the 2nd button :)

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> Remains Unchanged
End Sub

'~~> Start button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=TextBox1.Value, Origin:=437, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws2 = Sheets(1)

    lastRow = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws2.Range("A1"), _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Sub

'~~> 3rd button Code
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets.Add

    wb1.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ws2.Name & "!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C12", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12 _
    ).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ws1.Name & "!R3C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim strPath As String, FileName As String

Private Sub testFinder_Click()
    '~~> Open button
    Dim fileToOpen

    fileToOpen = Application _
    .GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileToOpen = False Then Exit Sub

    TextBox1.Value = fileToOpen

    FileName = GetFilenameFromPath(TextBox1.Value)
    strPath = Replace(TextBox1.Value, FileName, "")
End Sub

'~~> Start button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=strPath & FileName, Origin:=437, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws2 = Sheets(1)

    lastRow = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws2.Range("A1"), _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    LastCol = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws2.Range("A1"), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Sub

'~~> 3rd button Code
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Set ws1 = wb2.Sheets.Add

    wb2.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ws2.Name & "!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C" & LastCol, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "[" & wb2.Name & "]" & ws1.Name & "!R3C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion12
End Sub

Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, _
        Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: hi, i have tried.. but i think my group of users would prefer to use a more automated way instead... is it possible to stick to my kind of code? sorry if its alittle too demanding..

Comment: Yes, in that case, you will have to ask the user to make the relevant sheet active before running the code and then you "Activesheet" as Alex suggested. :)

Comment: Oh! ok.. I have tried using it again and realized i did not select it as an activesheet. But for my macro, i'm using a GUI, my GUI will open this text file as an excel file. The active sheet instead will be sheet1 not the text file.. Is there any way i can to make it the txt file an active sheet?

Comment: I think I know what you are trying to do :) However to be sure, can you post the code where you open the text and then use the above code?

Comment: i have posted the code.. its a userform code. I hope u can understand what i'm trying to do

Comment: Yes I do :) I had suspected that you would be using a similar kind of code. Give me sometime, I am updating my post above with new code

Comment: hi sid, it is showing error at the 3rd button, Set ws1 = ws1.Sheets.Add. Run time error

Comment: Set ws1 = ws1.Sheets.Add ===> should be Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets.Add. Also can you upload a sample text file in wikisend.com and share the link here so that I can give you a tested code?

Comment: Hi there, now the error is with the 2nd portion of the 3rd button... it states invalid procedure call or argument. btw, http://www.mediafire.com/?v3360l88230avu6 The link is some data that i come out randomly so that you can understand what i'm trying to do. Hope it helps!...

Comment: Thanks will look into it. BTW it is an excel file. I was expecting the text file.

Comment: i wanted to show u how my pivot table would look like.. anyway, the txt file looks something like the excel file in sheet 1.. just that it is being opened in excel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8440/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1204868)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the current sheet is available via `activesheet.name`.

```
 SourceData:= activesheet.name & "!R1C1:R1048576C12"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Sub AddPivot()

Dim shName As String
Dim shNames As String
Dim strFullRng As String
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim blPresent As Boolean

For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    shNames = shNames & UCase(wks.Name) & "|"
Next wks


Do
    shName = InputBox("Please enter the sheetname", "Create Pivot")

    If InStr(1, shNames, UCase(shName)) > 0 Then
        blPresent = True
    Else
        MsgBox ("That sheet name is invalid")
    End If

Loop Until blPresent

Set wks = Sheets.Add

strFullRng = shName & "!" & Sheets(shName).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Address
ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, strFullRng).CreatePivotTable wks.Cells(3, 1), "PivotTable1"


End Sub
```

Comment: hi, like what i have commented to Sid. I'm grateful of your help, but was wondering if it is possible to have an automated way to create pivot table? thank you!

Comment: As Sid has said you either need to make the user go to the active sheet and run the code from there - you could put a button on the correct sheet, or you need some way of working out which sheet is the data source. For example, you could check for certain words in column headings

Comment: I have retry and realized my macro didnt select the activesheet of data to create pivot table instead it takes sheet1 as the active sheet. Do you know how can i rectify this problem?